# C# interop.excel workbooks.opentext method fieldinfo doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-interop

Fieldinfo can read text file in different format, but it seems not to be working for me. I tried what is on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb223513.aspx.

```
object fieldInfo = new int[21, 2] {{ 1, 2 },{ 2, 2 },{ 3, 2 }, { 4, 2 },{ 5, 2 },{ 6, 2 },{ 7, 2 },{ 8, 1 },{ 9, 1 },{ 10, 1 },
            { 11, 1 },{ 12, 1 },{ 13, 1},{ 14, 2 },{ 15, 1},{ 16, 1 },{17, 2},{ 18, 2 },{ 19, 2 },{ 20, 2 }, { 21, 2 }

                        };
        xlApp.Workbooks.OpenText(myZdrive + @"\CI_System\Source_Files\" + myPosFile, XlPlatform.xlWindows, 1,
                                 XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited,
                                XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierNone, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, fieldInfo);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the Excel interop. Use the OpenXml SDK.

You can download it here:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124

Here is an article explaining how to use it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469465%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: My boss doesn't give me a option :(

Comment: Indentured servitude? Just kidding :)

Comment: Seriously though, the excel interop is a relic, and should not be used anymore. Plus, I think there are compatibility problems with it.

Comment: But i'm rewriting vba code using c#. Almost every excel method in vba has an corresponding one in excel.interop

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do with the interop that can't be done with OpenXml SDK. I think there are more limitations with the interop, actually.